# How can I pass an {id} property to my Next.js dynamic route using Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

I have a problem with passing the **`${id}`** property to my dynamic route **`[id]>page.jsx`**, which is inside the **`CartItemPage.jsx`** file. I'm using the Context API, similar to React, where I store an array of **`CartItems`** and render my Cart with this array. I have a home page and a catalog page, and there are **`ProductItem`** components. When I click on them, I need to navigate the user to **`CartItemPage[id]`** of that specific product, but I'm having trouble getting the **`id`** property.

Here is the code for my **`CartItem`** component (actually a product):

```
'use client';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from './CartItem.module.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAppStore } from '../../app/Context/store';

const CartItem = ({ data }) => {
    const [addedToCart, setAddedToCart] = useState(false);
    const { addToCart, cartItems } = useAppStore();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cartItems.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === data.id)) {
            setAddedToCart(true);
        } else {
            setAddedToCart(false);
        }
    }, [cartItems]);

    const handleAddToCart = data => {
        if (cartItems.some(cartItem => cartItem.title === data.title)) {
            setAddedToCart(true);
        } else {
            addToCart(data);
            setAddedToCart(true);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(cartItems);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.productCard}>
                <Link href={`/cartItemPage/${data.id}`}>
                    <div className='flex items-center flex-col'>
                        <img className={styles.productImage} src={data.image} alt={data.title} />
                        <h3 className={styles.productTitle}>{data.title}</h3>
                        <p className={styles.productPrice}>{data.price} $</p>

                        {/* Додаткові деталі */}
                    </div>
                </Link>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        handleAddToCart(data);
                    }}
                    className={addedToCart ? styles.addedButton : styles.addButton}
                >
                    {addedToCart ? 'У кошику' : 'До кошику'}
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CartItem;
```

here is a code of  **`CartItemPage`**, where i created **`[id] > page.jsx`**:

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useAppStore } from '@/app/Context/store';

const CartItemPage = ({ id }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const { addToCart, cartItems } = useAppStore();
    const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCartItem = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`);
                const data = await response.json(response.data);
                setCartItem(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };

        if (id) {
            fetchCartItem();
        }
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <>
            <div>id: {id}</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CartItemPage;
```

Comment: Where did that now deleted first paragraph come from? My imagination runs wild and all I can come up with as explanation is unbelievable for me.

Comment: why not share it using query params and Next.js router?

Comment: i can't use useRouter.query because in next.js 13.4> there is a problem with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hey there!

You simply have to rename the `id` parameter to `params` and if you want to refer to the `id` just use `params.id`.

Like here is your updated code for `CartItemPage.jsx`:

#### Edit

Also make sure that the `page.js` file for your `CartItemPage` is inside a directory called `[id]`. So the file structure should be `cart > [id] > page.js`.

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useAppStore } from "@/app/Context/store";

const CartItemPage = ({ params }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const { addToCart, cartItems } = useAppStore();
  const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCartItem = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`);
        const data = await response.json(response.data);
        setCartItem(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    if (params.id) {
      fetchCartItem();
    }
  }, [params]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>id: {params.id}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CartItemPage;
```